# Why do I need to explicitly link pthread and rt with new gcc and binutils?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, binutils

### Situation

I have a large multi-library c++ project that has been compiled on Debian Squeeze with its native gcc 4.4 compiler so far.
Now I wanted to benefit from a newer gcc version and its optimizations for a specific architecture, thus being able to use FMA and AVX instructions on my target platform. I have compiled gcc 4.9.1 from source and had to also compile new binutils because the linker did not support the instruction set I guess.

### Problem

With the new `gcc` and `ld` I now had to modify by cmake based build system to also link libraries like `pthread`, `rt` or `crypto` which I did not have to specify explicitly before. How is that? Did something change in the last versions of gcc or the linker that I should be aware of? Is there a way to get back the "old" behavior of not having to be that specific? Having to specify those linking dependencies makes my CMakeLists.txt less readable by cluttering it with platform specific if-clauses.

### Versions

**System gcc and ld:**

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.4.5-8' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)

$ /usr/bin/ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian)
2.20.1-system.20100303
```

**Custom gcc and ld:**

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --enable-languages=c++ --enable-threads --enable-threads=posix --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --without-included-gettext --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-checking=release --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-bootstrap
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)

$ /usr/local/bin/ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.24.51.20140916
```

Comment: I found the following link: https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking. Does it mean that I have to live with it and it's not worth trying to work around this "new" behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the proper CMake build of a thread-enable application should include detection of `Threads` library which indeed performs platform-dependent tests and then fills appropriate variables. See [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2003-September/004262.html) for more info.

Regarding the other libs in the question, I think that these libraries are platform specific, so you have to add them only on a particular platform. And indeed they are required on those platforms. Why with your previous compiler the program doesn't need these libraries, at least explicitly specified? Maybe because they are implicitly linked in. Try to `gcc -dumpspecs` for both compiler versions and compare the output.